# Cálculo errado de porcentagem

Tags: c, matemática

Como exatamente é feito para utilizar o `switch` de forma correta?

Aqui no código, o `case` 1 e 2, funcionam normalmente, porém no `case` 3 e 4, na hora da divisão por 2, ou por 3, para saber as parcelas, sempre dá errado o resultado (parece que tá dividindo por 22 ou 23).

Ou o `switch` não faz esse tipo de operação? Eu sei que dá pra fazer sem ser switch, porém a minha professora quer.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

float valorT, valorF, Vparcelas;
int op;

main()
{
    printf("Digite o valor total da sua compra: ");
    scanf("%f", &valorT);
    printf("Digite o numero da opcao de pagamento, estao listadas abaixo: \n");

    printf("1-Dinheiro\n2-Cartao debito\n3-Cartao credito 2x\n4-Cartao credito 3x\n");
    scanf("%d", &op);

    if(op > 4){
        printf("Opcao invalida!\n");
    }

    switch(op){
        case 1: valorF = valorT*0.1;
        printf("O valor total da sua conta ficou: %0.2f", valorT-valorF);
        break;

        case 2: valorF = valorT*0.2;
        printf("O valor total da sua conta ficou: %0.2f", valorT-valorF);
        break;

        case 3: valorF = valorT*0.1;
        Vparcelas = valorF/2; //ISSO DA ERRADO
        printf("O valor total da sua conta ficou: %0.2f,\ne das 3 parcelas: %0.2f\n", valorT+valorF, Vparcelas);
        break;

        case 4: valorF = valorT*0.15;
        Vparcelas = valorF/3; //ISSO TAMBEM
        printf("O valor total da sua conta ficou: %0.2f,\ne das 3 parcelas: %0.2f\n", valorT+valorF, Vparcelas);
        break;
    }



    return 0;


}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O código tem alguns problemas, não falarei de todos, principalmente os de organização (que ajudaria entender o problema) e coisas que não importam para um exercício, por exemplo que `float` não serve para valor monetário.

Entendo que os dois primeiros queira dar um desconto (se não for isso está esquisito demais, a pergunta não deixa claro isso). O valor original é sempre base 1. Então o desconto não precisa de uma conta composta, basta multiplicar pela porcentagem do valor do valor final já dado o desconto, então se é 10% de desconto basta multiplicar por `0.9`.

Para os outros entendo que haverá acréscimo, então é fazer o oposto, multiplica pelo valor já com o acréscimo, portanto se é 10% o valor a usar será `1.1`.

Se fizer essas simplificações fica mais fácil entender e aí a conta do valor das parcelas se torna automático. Fazendo algo linear evita problemas.

Note que se digitasse 0 ou negativo na opção o código daria erro também. E não tem uma validação se o valor total está de acordo com o que se espera, mas o exercício não deve estar pedindo isso.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    float valorT, valorF;
    int op;
    printf("Digite o valor total da sua compra: ");
    scanf("%f", &valorT);
    printf("Digite o numero da opcao de pagamento, estao listadas abaixo: \n");
    printf("1-Dinheiro\n2-Cartao debito\n3-Cartao credito 2x\n4-Cartao credito 3x\n");
    scanf("%d", &op);
    switch (op) {
    case 1:
        printf("O valor total da sua conta ficou: %0.2f", valorT * 0.9);
        break;
    case 2:
        printf("O valor total da sua conta ficou: %0.2f", valorT * 0.8);
        break;
    case 3:
        valorF = valorT * 1.1;
        printf("O valor total da sua conta ficou: %0.2f,\ne das 3 parcelas: %0.2f\n", valorF, valorF / 2);
        break;
    case 4:
        valorF = valorT * 1.15;
        printf("O valor total da sua conta ficou: %0.2f,\ne das 3 parcelas: %0.2f\n", valorF, valorF / 3);
        break;
    default:
        printf("Opcao invalida!\n");
    }
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/nwDhWj). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/@maniero/Discountc). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/C/Math/Discount.c).

Comment: ah, entendi! mas voce saberia me explicar pq na hora da divisao por 2 ou 3 no eu codigo, estava dividindo por 22 e 23 respectivamente.. pelo menos pelo o que eu testei, pq se eu colocasse 1260,23 o resultado das 2 parcelas da 63,01

Comment: O cálculo está todo errado. As fórmulas não são essas, eu não sei de onde tirou isso, então nem cabe ficar procurando motivos para isso.

Answer (score 1):

O problema está nas suas contas e não na sua programação, o switch nada mais é que um if multi-condição.

Do seu código imagino que:

- Se o cliente pagar em duas parcelas terá um acréscimo de 10%.

```
valorF = valorT*0.1; //esse é o valor dos juros
Vparcelas = (valorT + valorF)/2;
```

- Se o cliente pagar em três parcelas terá um acréscimo de 15%.

```
valorF = valorT*0.15;
Vparcelas = (valorT + valorF)/3;
```

Ajuste também a conferência do valor de entrada (se não for menor que um):

```
if(op > 4 || op < 1){
  printf("Opcao invalida!\n");
}
```

---

Se não for isso por gentileza descreva melhor o problema e o que é cada variável; e coloque valores de entrada e saída esperada.

Answer (score -3):

O problema esta na conta, provavelmente você errou na hora de colocar os multiplicadores. Se você substituir o 0.x por 1.x deve resolver o problema. Ou fazer como o Edney falou e colocar como uma somatoria